# curl returns empty output when json-rpc

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc, bitcoin-cli, bitcoin.conf

I am not able to get JSON-RPC response via curl. It seems like is not accepting requests.

My bitcoin.conf

```
rpcuser=USER
rpcpassword=PASS
server=1
rpcport=9332
```

Running daemon

```
$ bitcoind -conf=~/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf -daemon
Bitcoin server starting
```

Checking cli

```
$ bitcoin-cli -conf=~/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf getinfo
{
  "version": 140200,
  "protocolversion": 70015,
  "walletversion": 130000,
  "balance": 0.00000000,
  "blocks": 439348,
  "timeoffset": 0,
  "connections": 8,
  "proxy": "",
  "difficulty": 254620187304.0614,
  "testnet": false,
  "keypoololdest": 1500029964,
  "keypoolsize": 100,
  "paytxfee": 0.00000000,
  "relayfee": 0.00001000,
  "errors": ""
}
```

Testing curl

```
$ curl http://localhost:3333
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 3333: Connection refused
```

Of course, the port is wrong:

```
$ curl http://localhost:9332
JSONRPC server handles only POST requests
```

Making a post

```
$ curl http://localhost:8332 -H 'content-type:text/plain;' --data-binary ''
```

The output is always empty, doesn't matter if I add data or user,password. Is always empty:

```
$ curl http://localhost:9332 -H 'content-type:text/plain;' --data-binary ''
$ curl http://localhost:9332 -H 'content-type:text/plain;' --data-binary ''
$ curl http://USER:PASS@localhost:9332 -H 'content-type:text/plain;' --data-binary ''
$ curl http://USER:PASS@localhost:9332 -H 'content-type:text/plain;' --data-binary '{"jsonrpc":"1.0","id":"curltext","method":"getinfo","params":[]}'
$ curl --user USER:PASS http://localhost:9332 -H 'content-type:text/plain;' --data-binary '{"jsonrpc":"1.0","id":"curltext","method":"getinfo","params":[]}'
```

Any ideas why is this happening? Don't know what else to try.

Comment: Can you add the verbose option and tell us what is says?  
 `-v / --verbose`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on Amazon AWS try this:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

I had the same problem and it took me hours to figure out that the server was blocking connections. I thought it wasn't the problem because my AWS security group allowed it. But apparently the server was blocking it directly.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone trying to connect locally to a wallet:

I managed to get mine working locally by changing `rpcallowip` and `rpcconnect` from `127.0.0.1` to my actual local I.P. address (e.g. `192.168.0.2`), seems that by using default `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` does not always work.

Answer (score -1):

add this to bitcoin.conf

```
rpcallowip=0.0.0.0/0
```

allow all ip

Comment: This is incredibly insecure. You should only allow the IPs you will be connecting from.

Comment: this allowed me to test locally after hours of trying specific ips.  Will not use for production though.